# Standalone java base java formatter

Tags: java, format, coding-style, executable-jar

Is there a Java-based program (executable-jar) that can format java code (indenting/spacing)?

If it would be configurable, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You bet: [JIndent](http://www.jindent.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) is another and FREE.
[CheckStyle:Indentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#Indentation).

Comment: Can you give a specific example of using this tool?

Comment: Once I have used this as a Netbeans plugin. There are plugins available for Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans, JBuilder, JEdit and Emacs JDE. The plugin I used before is http://www.sickboy.cz/checkstyle/screenshots.html

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/google/google-java-format
Google Java format. It isn't configurable.
You could also use clang-format and prettier to format Java code. Those aren't jars, though. Clang-format is configurable; prettier is opinionated.